# Use JavaScript Node command line tool in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-chrome

Hey I have an app written in js being accessed by  `$ node script.js`

I want to visualize the output of it and thought it'd be a good idea to just "wrap" a HTML page around it. For example in the output in the terminal there are 2 values gradually increasing and I'd like to process both of them in a way that they could represent 2 bars that, according to the 2 values, rise accordingly.

However, I've never done anything in JS and I don't really know the best way to do it.

I found http://iceddev.com/blog/node-js-in-chrome/ to host a local server to run my .js on this but not even the console.log or any errors in the code in the index.js (which is basically opening the server and contains the content you want to see when navigating to it in Chrome) show up in the Chrome console so I am wondering if there is something else I can do here.

Comment: If you're using NodeJS specific methods and libraries it won't work in the browser. Look into browserpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your script in the browser I recommended you to look this package http://browserify.org/ it compile your js script into browser compatible js